# Map of related tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I put together this mind map to represent approximate relationships I see between tags. Many tags do not fit well into a tree structure, so I've taken liberties in a few areas. Hopefully this is useful for writing tag wikis and excerpts, identifying areas of overlap, and for pruning the less useful tags on this site.

[image: mind map of popular tags on Ask Different]

#### Navigating this map

- Software that is mostly unique to Apple is all along the right-hand side, and divided into that which is applicable only to macOS, only to iOS, or is shared between iOS and macOS.
- Along the left-hand side are the broader categories of hardware and software, with all tags for Apple hardware grouped together under the  symbol.
- There's a wildcard `*` group for a lot of general terminology that isn't really specific to Apple hardware or software.
- Although labels are arranged in branches, this was not an attempt to model a strict hierarchy. Many groups have been compressed into an elongated branch to shrink the map and help with readability.

Comment: Awesome stuff indeed!

Comment: Very nice, thanks for doing this!  Upvoted.

Comment: XMind, or what?

Comment: @LаngLаngС yes, XMind

Comment: Ahhrgh. (No criticism. Am looking *just now* for a cross-platform macOS/Linux desktop cross/hybrid between XMind and OmniGraffle. Too bad.) If you add the 'application used' to the post, you may flag all my comments as obsolete…

Answer (score 1):

What a wonderful mind map and hierarchy - I will use this when thinking on how I review edits / tag questions / think about if something is a [tag](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) or [meta-tag](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-tag)

The one thing I would have a hard time doing is not making services a major category and moving the cloud version / most of iOS and macos overlap under services - it’s like any org that grows - at some point you implement matrix and dotted lines since Photos app on iOS depends on Photos service design, but most people think of the app they first use on the device and not the service that guided and shaped what the app could even be or do.